# left and right properties

Tags: css

I'm trying to get my head around CSS positioning, and I'm slightly confused by the `left` and `right` properties. I know that the properties take values which determine how far from the left or right edge of a container the element will be placed. But what if the left and right properties are set in such a way where it is impossible to satisfy both at once? Which property has precedence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends, but if your `position` is `fixed` or `absolute` and you haven't defined `width`, it will be resized. When it *is* defined, [it appears `top` and `left` take precedence](http://jsfiddle.net/nFJkb/).

Answer (score -1):

You will only be using left or right, not both at the same time. Typically when you give an element a position of absolute you declare 1 or 2 sides to position from. For example, you might position a div 5px from the top. You could also position the div 5px from the top and 10px from the left.

Comment: Actually, I use both a lot to do fancy positioning and sizing effects when `height: 100%` doesn't work.